# how to filter out sqlite output

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, output

there is my code

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('someDB.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT column FROM someDB")
result = c.fetchall()
```

as you see it connects to db, selects a column and fetches it into result
by the way there is 4 rows in it, 1st and 4th are null
when i print result it gives me this

```
[(None,), ('useful',), ('useful',), (None,)]
```

why are there brackets before and after every element; are brackets elements too; how do i get rid of them leaving only 'None's and 'useful's

the desired output is

```
[None, 'useful', 'useful', None]
```

Comment: what is the desired output? can you edit the question to show that please.

Comment: @aws_apprentice edited

Comment: fetchall() returns a list => [result1, result2, ..., resultn]. Every result can consist of multiple columns (you selected just one) => (column1, column2, ....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(result))

[None, 'useful', 'useful', None]
```

The reason your results are returned the way they are is because the `Cursor` object returns `Row` objects. This is obviously more apparent/useful when you select more than 1 column from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you always need to get the first element for every tuple (singleton) in your list, the "universal" way:

```py
inputs = [(None,), ('useful',), ('useful',), (None,)]
outputs = []
for tuples in inputs:
  outputs.append(tuples[0])
```

If you want something a bit more pythonic, then you can use python's [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
outputs = [tuples[0] for tuples in inputs]
```

You could also use a variant, using the ["spread" operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```py
outputs = [first_element for (first_element, *other_elements) in inputs]
```

And finally, maybe the best way (I can think of):

```py
outputs = [first_element for (first_element, ) in inputs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if the database may be large, it might be suboptimal to first build a list of 1-tuples to convert it into a list of values. The Python documentation for sqlite3 advertise to use `fetchmany` with its default value for size for optimal performances.

The final list could be built this way:

```
result = []
while True:
    chunk = c.fetchmany()
    if len(chunk) == 0: break
    result.extend([row[0] for row in chunk])
```

Or if you prefere to build the list in one single comprehension by using a generator:

```
def chunks(cursor):
    while True:
        chunk = c.fetchmany()
        if len(chunk) == 0: return
        yield chunk

...
result = [row[0] for chunk in chunks(c) for row in chunk]
```